# How to insert a captcha in to my application's registration form using OmniAuth-identity for rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I am trying to insert a captcha in to my application's registration form. I need place a controller helper method to check whether the captcha is valid. I'm using OmniAuth-identity for my simple authentication, which does not provide a controller method. The user's registration form posts directly to the OmniAuth handler and so can't able to check the this helper method that is

```
if verify_recaptcha(:model => @post, :message => "Oh! It's error with reCAPTCHA!") && @post.save
    # ...
else
    # ...
end
```

Can anyone please help me on this how to place a controller helper method using OmniAuth-identity?

Comment: This is only personal opinion but i find captchas very annoying, especially from a user point of view (dont forget about the users, afterall they will decide if your site is any good). If your just looking to stop spam, might i suggest using the Honey Trap method..create a hidden text field and implement a rule that if this hidden field is filled in then do not post the form

Answer (score 0):

The readme gives a hint on hooking up Omniauth-Identity lifecycle events to controller actions. Here's an example adapted to fit what your asking for:

```
# application.rb
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity,
    :fields => [:email],
    :on_login => UsersController.action(:login)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have tried this by calling a method in my identities controller. But no use. Can you please explain this with any example .

Comment: Could you update your question with what you've tried? It's hard to debug the problem without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

this [pr](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity/pull/86) will be helpful.

for example:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity,  on_validation: lambda {|env| Captcha.valid_captcha?(env)}
end
```